# Is there a server hosted version of the iOS simulator? Or: How to use an iOS app without Mac and iOS devices

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

I know this question sounds silly at first glance, but how could customers and testers who do not have an Apple iPad or iPhone to use and test my app actually "run" the app?

Is there something like a web hosted service, which would allow them to test it in a web browser instead on a real device?

Comment: No such thing exists.

Comment: Here's a sillier question - why would your customers (who are paying you to develop an iOS app) not actually have an iOS device?

Comment: If your target audience does not have ios devices then why make an ios app and not an HTML5 web app.

Comment: Unicorn: A few of my target users do not have iOS devices yet, but might reconsider their decision if they like the app. Around 20% of the users I have invited to a beta test use Samsung Galaxy tablets.

Comment: Well then why did you invite them to test it if they can't test it?

Comment: Oh and do @Unicorn instead of what you did so it will notify me of your message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no official native full-featured iOS simulator for the web. But if you create one, please tell me.

Comment: Can't you run Xcode and the simulator in on a (virtualized) Mac OS server and give your users remote access to it (Remote Desktop), macstadium.com offers OS X server hosting for example.

Comment: You could but I really doubt the value in that.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be a service like [app.io](https://app.io).

I believe they have a free tier that would allow you to run your app on the web on a limited basis.